# Aws IAM role Chaining , session timeout need to be more than 2 hours to run job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, data-processing, identity-management

I am working on Data processing in which I have EKS cluster in one account and doing processing in second aws account , so we are assuming IAM role from One account to another and performing processing, but assuming role forming a IAM Chaining which limit the temporary session timeout to 1 hour but processing needs more that 2 hours to complete.

I tried to refresh the session before its expire like but I have single jar command which take more than 1 hour to process  because of that refreshing session is also not working.

I want the session should not expire until the processing completed
or session should be valid at least 2 hours

Comment: Which version of AWS SDK are you using? v1 or v2

Comment: no accessing through aws CLI

Comment: Do you have the source code of jar file?